# Powershell script to import log file into SQL table

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm wanting to import a log file into sql table using powershell. Has anyone does this?
The log has some structure at the bottom but I would like to skip the top 13 rows.

Sample Log: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/yFajtwkfT73JqojMiEZMz-_1cy6XQlHtqP5ibkJbfpM=w484-h228-p-no

Powershell script for SQL connection:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=Server\Development;Database=Development;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand


$SqlCmd.CommandText = "BULK INSERT Development..CUBE_LOG 
FROM 'D:\POWERCUBE_SQL_LOG\result.txt'
WITH (CODEPAGE='RAW' ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', DATAFILETYPE='widechar')"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.Open()
$sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: It's beneficial to describe the particular error/incorrect results you are encountering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the First Row Argument in bulk insert.

Reference : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

```
WITH (CODEPAGE='RAW' ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',FIRSTROW = 14,DATAFILETYPE='widechar')"
```